# Elisp: can't get matched group from regex

Tags: emacs, elisp

Code:

```
(if 
      (string-match-p "\\(.*\\)/www/sites" 
                      "/var/www/lwt/www/sites/all/modules/bundles/bundles.module")
      (match-string-no-properties 1 
                      "/var/www/lwt/www/sites/all/modules/bundles/bundles.module")
      "false"
)
```

Here I expected to get "/var/www/lwt", but I get `nil`. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As its docstring tells you:

> `string-match-p` is a compiled Lisp function in `subr.el'.
>
> (string-match-p REGEXP STRING &optional START)
>
> Same as `string-match' except **this function does not change the match data.**

So you should be using `string-match`.